# How do I add a new XML / JavaScript like language to Ace Editor?

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, ace-editor

I would like to add MXML support to Ace Editor but I'm not sure where to start. Is there a guide that I can use to guide me through it? Can I take an existing language module and rename it and have it work?

It's an XML document and it uses namespaces. it is very similar to HTML markup in that it has a Script tag where you can type code. The script is very similar to JavaScript except you can optionally type the variables (it is JavaScript / ES4). The CSS is very similar to CSS except it adds namespaces to that as well.

Example MXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 

                       frameRate="30"
                       showStatusBar="false"
                       minWidth="720"
                       minHeight="480"
                       initialize="initializeHandler(event)"
                       backgroundColor="#242424"
                       >

    <fx:Style source="fonts.css"/>

    <fx:Style source="styles.css"/>

    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
        @namespace components "components.*";

        s|ToggleSwitch
        {
            accentColor: #3F7FBA;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            fontSize: 27;
            skinClass: ClassReference("spark.skins.mobile.ToggleSwitchSkin");
            slideDuration: 125;
             /*textShadowAlpha: .65;
           textShadowColor: #000000;*/
        }

        s|TextArea
        {
            skinClass: ClassReference("spark.skins.spark.TextAreaSkin");
        }

        s|Label {
            paddingLeft: 20;
        }

        .headerLabels {
            paddingLeft: 20;
        }

        #myLabel {
            paddingLeft: 20;
        }

    </fx:Style>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            /**
             * Error: Could not find compiled resource bundle 'logging' for locale 'en_US'
             * 
             * Caused by when I switched to using external library
             **/

            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
                width = Capabilities.screenResolutionX*.85;
                height = Capabilities.screenResolutionY*.88;
                center();
            }

            // Align native AIR application window horizontally and vertically
            protected function center():void {
                nativeWindow.x = (Capabilities.screenResolutionX - width) / 2;
                nativeWindow.y = (Capabilities.screenResolutionY - height) / 2 - 32;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>

        <utils:RegisterSingleton id="registerSingleton" 
                                 target="{manager}" />
        <controller:ApplicationController id="manager" isDesktop="true"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <components:MainGroup id="mainGroup" width="100%" height="100%"/>

</s:Application>
```

If it makes it easier it's XML + ActionScript; two modes that are already supported.

Comment: I added the Flex and MXML tag to this question because maybe someone who knows Flex and MXML knows how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The wiki entry for creating or extending a mode should have all the answers you need :
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Creating-or-Extending-an-Edit-Mode